# why i'm getting this error (Must declare the scalar variable "@param2"). for my code

Tags: c#

why i'm getting this error Must declare the scalar variable "@param2". for my code

```
string query = "INSERT INTO cdr_info VALUES(@param2,'" + Values[1] + "' , '" + Values[2] + "',  '" + Values[3] + "',  '" + Values[5] + "',  '" + Values[7] + "',  '" + Values[8] + "', '" + Values[9] + "'," +             " '" + Values[10] + "',  '" + Values[12] + "',  '" + Values[13] + "',  '" + Values[14] + "', '" + Values[17] + "', '" + Values[21] + "',  '" + Values[23] + "',  '" + Values[24] + "',  '" + Values[25] + "','" + Values[26] + "',  '" + Values[27] + "', '" + Values[28] + "', '" + Values[29] + "', " +             " '" + Values[30] + "', '" + Values[31] + "',  '" + Values[32] + "',  '" + Values[34] + "'," +             "'" + Values[35] + "',  '" + Values[37] + "',  '" + Values[38] + "','" + Values[39] + "', '" + Values[40] + "', '" + Values[41] + "','" + Values[45] + "',  '" + Values[46] + "',  '" + Values[47] + "',  '" + Values[48] + "'," +             " '" + Values[52] + "', '" + Values[53] + "',  '" + Values[55] + "',  '" + Values[59] + "',  '" + Values[64] + "'," +             "'" + Values[71] + "', '" + Values[75] + "',  '" + Values[85] + "', '" + Values[93] + "', '" + Values[94] + "',  '" + Values[95] + "', '" + Values[96] + "',  '" + Values[97] + "', '" + Values[98] + "',    '" + Values[105] + "',  '" + Values[106] + "')";                                                                  

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2",Values[0]);
cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);                                 
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: There is 0% chance of getting such a long statement right. If you need to pass so many fields to the statement, use String.Join to create the parameter list in `VALUES(...)` and a loop to pass the actual parameter values in `AddWithValue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you reassign the command after you added the parameter to it.

Try putting the instructions in this order:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2",Values[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not perfect but to give you a good idea...

```
  var sqlString = new StringBuilder();

  sqlString.Append("INSERT INTO cdr_info VALUES(@param2,'");
  sqlString.Append("Values[1] + "' , '" + Values[2] + "',  '" + Values[3] + "',  '" + Values[5] + "',  '" + Values[7] + "',  '" + Values[8] + "', '" + Values[9] + "',");
  sqlString.Append("" '" + Values[10] + "',  '" + Values[12] + "',  '" + Values[13] + "',  '" + Values[14] + "', '" + Values[17] + "', '" + Values[21] + "',  '" + Values[23] + "',  '"");
  sqlString.Append("Values[24] + "',  '" + Values[25] + "','" + Values[26] + "',  '" + Values[27] + "', '" + Values[28] + "', '"");
  sqlString.Append("Values[29] + "', " +             " '" + Values[30] + "', '" + Values[31] + "',  '" + Values[32] + "',  '" + Values[34] + "'," +             "'" + Values[35]");
  sqlString.Append("Values[35] + "',  '" + Values[37] + "',  '" + Values[38] + "','" + Values[39] + "', '" + Values[40] + "', '" + Values[41] + "','" + Values[45] + "',  '" + Values[46] + "',  '" + Values[47] + "',  '" + Values[48] + "'," +             " '" + Values[52]);
  sqlString.Append(""', '" + Values[53] + "',  '" + Values[55] + "',  '" + Values[59] + "',  '" + Values[64]")
  sqlString.Append("'," +             "'" + Values[71] + "', '" + Values[75] + "',  '" + Values[85] + "', '" + Values[93] + "', '" + Values[94] + "',  '" + Values[95] + "', '" + Values[96])
  sqlString.Append(""',  '" + Values[97] + "', '" + Values[98] + "',    '" + Values[105] + "',  '" + Values[106] + "')""");

  cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlString , con);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2",Values[0]);
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Honestly though I find it hard to believe theres not a better way to do this.

PS- Whats all the white spaces for?

"Values[29] + "', " +             " '" + Values[30]